# How to know the coordinates of a particular cell in a table

Tags: extjs, watir

I am working with Watir to automate some browser task, but am unable to automate the table which is used in EXTJS. I found an alternative to click on the table elements using autoit, so is there anyway to know the coordinates of the particular cell with respective to the browser in Watir?

Comment: is there any solution to my question ??

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) method in javascript.

Assuming that `e` is the Watir element (eg `e = browser.table.td`) you want the coordinates of, you can do the following in watir-webdriver:

```
browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top', e) 
browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().right', e) 
browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom', e) 
browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().left', e)
```

In watir-classic, the same would be done using:

```
e.document.getBoundingClientRect.top
e.document.getBoundingClientRect.right
e.document.getBoundingClientRect.bottom
e.document.getBoundingClientRect.left
```

This would give you the information for the bounding rectangle around the element. You could get a coordinate by combining the information (eg for the top left corner).

Comment: Epic answer, wasn't aware of the method .. and it's much faster than the xpath.. Thanks Justin!